# What's the difference between fourier series and power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, fourier-series

Can anyone help me out with this one? The question was asked by a professor in my college but I have no idea how to answer this.

Comment: If you point your mouse to the tags below the question, you get short descriptions of them.

Comment: have you tried the Wikipedia already?